# Matlab: plot is only graphing last value in vector

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, plot

I need the following code to plot the range of values of C(i) against the values of x. So based on the code at the x = 1, I need C(1), at x = 2, C(2) and so on... A simple problem Im sure, please help!

```
clear all; clc;
n = 15
x = 1:(n-1)
T = 500;
D = T./(n-x)

for i=1:13
C(i) = D(i+1) - D(i)
end

plot(x, C(i), 'rx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is this,

```
clear 
clc
close all

n = 15;
x = 1:(n-1);
T = 500;
D = T./(n-x);

C = zeros(length(x) - 1, 1);

for i=1:13
    C(i) = D(i+1) - D(i);
end

figure, plot(C, 'rx')
```

It is better to preallocate the `C` variable, so you can plot it then.

The `C(i)` only gave you the last number because after the for `i` is 13 and `C(i)`as you had it only gives you `C` in the 13th position.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
plot(x, C(i), 'rx')
```

To:

```
plot(x(1:end-1), C, 'rx')
```

Actually, you could replace your `for` loop with this:

```
C = diff(D);
```

Which calculates the difference between consecutive elements.

Comment: Only now I saw you were calculating the difference between consecutive values. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) I've edited my answer providing you an alternative to your `for` loop.